# What are backup possibilities for DashDB with Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

We have an application on Bluemix that connects to a DashDB database. I could not find any mention of backup in the graphical interface.

- Is it possible possible to get a full backup?
- Does the service support backup automatically?

Any links to resources would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some info on backups

For **dashDB managed** service: Encrypted backups on the full database are done daily. The last two backups are retained. Point-in-time restores are not available.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/managed_service.html